# Identify this breed of grass that is struggling during winter - and help it

Tags: identification, grass, lawn-repair

I need some help identify this breed of grass - to work out what it might need to thrive a little more.

It is growing in SE Queensland, Aus and it's currently winter here. It gets very little direct sunlight with the angle of the sun this time of year due to nearby trees/houses. It's on a hill but has been getting a fair bit of water from rain.

In general it has gotten quite sparse, brown for the first 3-4cm with green on the tips. It is also trying to grow very tall, pointing straight up with no leaves down low at all.

What is the breed, so I can search more for what it likes, and what might it need to thicken up and green down?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be  Cynodon dactylon (Couch grass).
Best ask your local friends about it.

An African summer grass. As long as you dont grow veggies or fruit trees it will be an OK lawn grass.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynodon_dactylon

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right. From google it seems it's not a very shade tolerant grass, so there's not a lot I can do for apart from wait for summer.